# Dropdown opens on click, closes when mouse moves away

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've only managed to make it open on hover using css, but I don't know how to combine the two and have it opened when clicked and closed when mouse moves away. I'm also very sorry if this question has appeared before, but I've searched everywhere and couldn't find an answer.

This is my code so far:

```
<div class="col-md-3"><div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle text-left border-0 rounded-0 py-2" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
    <i class="fa fa-plus float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-minus float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>

  </button>

  <div class="dropdown-menu rounded-0 border-0" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div></div>

body {
  background: #eeeeee;
}

.btn {
  width: 100%;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vw;
}

.dropdown:active .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0;
 }

.dropdown-toggle:after {
    display:none;  
}
.btn:active .fa-plus {
    display:none
}
```

Currently, it opens/closes on click. And those fontawesome icons are there because I'm trying to make them change, too.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit

Register the `mouseleave` event on `.dropdown-menu` and cancel event bubbling. Also, I had mentioned `.dropdown-toggle`, it should be `data-toggle`, sorry. BTW, changed `.dropdown-toggle` class to `.data-toggle` that shouldn't matter but important when you cut and paste.

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('.data-toggle').dropdown("toggle");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

---

### Old

Target the <del>`.dropdown-toggle`</del> the element with the `data-toggle` , attribute, it's BS's primary component involved in all things involving the [dropdown component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-javascript-1).
Use the following:

```
$('.dropdown').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown("toggle"); 
});
```

**Snippet**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title></title>
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<style>
body { background: #eeeeee; }
.btn { width: 100%; }
.dropdown-menu { width: 100%; height: 100vw; }
.dropdown:active .dropdown-menu { display: block; margin-top: 0; }
.dropdown-toggle:after { display: none; }
.btn:active .fa-plus { display: none }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header> </header>
<section id="testA">
   <div class="col-md-3">
   
      <div class="dropdown closed">
      
         <button class="data-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown trigger
          
         Dropdown button 
         <i class="fa fa-minus float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
         <i class="fa fa-plus float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
         
         </button>
         
         <div class="dropdown-menu rounded-0 border-0" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"> 
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a> 
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a> 
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> </div>
      </div>
      
   </div>
   
</section>
<footer> </footer>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script> 
<script>


 $('.dropdown-menu').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
  $('.data-toggle').dropdown("toggle");
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, zer00ne! There's just one bug about this. When I click on it, it opens and closes when mouse moves away. But it opens again on hover when I move mouse back. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Retros That's very odd, I see it's honoring the `mouseleave` event regardless. Ok a condition must be enforced, standby for update.

Comment: @Retros ok, that was harder than I had anticipated. I fixed that behavior by targeting the menu and preventing event bubbling.

Comment: Thank you so much, zer00ne! I'd buy you a beer if I could!